# Find count of sub arrays of zeros in an array

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I need to find the count of sub arrays of zeros in an array:

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Result should be: `3` because we have `0, 0`, `0` and `0, 0, 0`.

Counting the number of zeros (6) will not work.

Comment: What do you mean with "continuous", and what do you mean with "result should be 3"?

Comment: Did a semester start or something? Seems early.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: ...Also, though we know what you mean by "sub arrays of zeroes" it would be more accurate to say something like, "numbers of groups of consecutive zeros".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) and [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) might work:

```
array
  .chunk_while(&:==)               # [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1]]
  .count { |arr| arr.include?(0) } # 3
```

Or [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-join), [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-scan) and [`length`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-length):

```
arr
  .join         # "11100111101110001"
  .scan(/(0+)/) # [["00"], ["0"], ["000"]]
  .length       # 3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
array.join.squeeze('0').count('0')
  #=> 3
```

We have

```
s = array.join
  #=> "11100111101110001" 
t = s.squeeze('0')
  #=> "11101111011101" 
t.count('0')
  #=> 3
```

Note one could squeeze all the characters, not just the zeroes (`squeeze` as opposed to `squeeze('0')`).

Another way:

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

array.select.with_index(1) { |n,i| n.zero? && array[i] != 0 }.size
  #=> 3
```

When, as here, the last element of `array` is a zero, `array[i] #=> nil` when `i = array.size` (since `i` goes from `1` to `array.size`).

Comment: Clever use of `#squeeze` but the unspoken assumption is that the arrays are always as presented (i.e. only zeros and ones).

Comment: @muistooshort, I don't think that assumption is necessary provide the element of interest is a single digit. Note that I could have just squeezed the zeroes. In fact, that would probably be better. I debated whether that solution is a hack and came down on the side it's not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable#chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and [`Enumerable#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) to handle this as well like so:

**Option 1:**

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
arr.chunk(&:zero?).count(&:first)
#=> 3
```

`chunk` will group consecutive elements together by their return value in the form of `[return_value, [*elements]]` so in this case `chunk(&:zero?)` will create groups like so

```
arr.chunk(&:zero?).to_a
#=>  [[false, [1, 1, 1]], 
#     [true, [0, 0]], 
#     [false, [1, 1, 1, 1]], 
#     [true, [0]], 
#     [false, [1, 1, 1]], 
#     [true, [0, 0, 0]], 
#     [false, [1]]]
```

However `chunk` does not create a new `Array` (thus the `to_a` above to show the structure) instead it creates an `Enumerator` that stores this block of code and evaluates the return value upon subsequent method calls.

In this case we are then calling `count(&:first)` since `count` will only count the elements for which the block returns a truthy value (not `nil` or `false`).

**Option 2:**

```
arr.chunk {|e| e.zero? || nil}.count
#=> 3
```

Very similar to Option 1 this works because `chunk` will drop all elements where the return value is `nil` meaning

```
arr.chunk {|e| e.zero? || nil}.to_a 
#=> [[true, [0, 0]], [true, [0]], [true, [0, 0, 0]]]
```

**Bonus:** (just for fun in case you need to count other consecutive elements)

```
groups = arr.chunk(&:itself)
  .each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] =[]}) do |(e,arr),obj| 
    obj[e] << arr
  end
#=> {1=>[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1]], 
#    0=>[[0, 0], [0], [0, 0, 0]]}
groups[0].size 
#=> 3
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the `chunk(&:zero?)` step, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way...

```
array.each_with_object([]){ |a, ary| ary << a unless ary.last == a }.count(&:zero?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this solution to understand the basic solution's idea of this problem.

This is **c++** solution for counting number of **0** sub-array. Increment result when we get a **0**. And when we get more than one zero then don't count for them.

```
int n = arr.size();
int cnt = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(i > 0 && arr[i] == arr[i-1]) {
        continue;
    }
    if(arr[i] == 0) {
        cnt++;
    }
}
cout << cnt << endl;
```

Comment: What if `array` begins with a zero?

Comment: Providing a C++ solution here is not especially helpful given the Ruby tag. That's because there's really only one way to obtain a solution with C++: step through the array looking for zeroes, then see if the zero is preceded by (or followed by) a zero. By contrast, the other answers illustrate the myriad ways the problem can be addressed using Ruby. If it were a different problem with a Ruby tag it's possible an innovate C++ solution might suggest a worthwhile Ruby approach, but that seems a stretch.

Comment: This solution will work also if array begins with a zero.
In that case second if condition will be executed and that will increment `cnt`. @CarySwoveland

Comment: Yes. My mistake.